# Highlight Borders When Mouseover Fill Area - Leaflet-R

Tags: r, leaflet

Following the guidance of @TimSalabim, I separated the borders and fill of my neighbourhood polygons so that I could order them appropriately with zIndex.

https://lawsblog.netlify.com/post/leaflet-map/

If I place the `highlightOptions()` function within the `addPolygons(neighbourhood fill)` function, I don't know how to increase the border of the polygon upon mouseover.

If I place the `highlightOptions()` function within the `addPolylines(neighbourhood border)` function I can CAREFULLY mouse-over just the borders and the widths increase. That's the behavior I want, when I mouse-over any part of the neighbourhood area.

Now that I've separated the fill and borders of the polygons how do I increase the border width when I mouse-over the fill area?

```
# Add hood borders
  addPolylines(data = borders, 
               color = "white",
               opacity = 1, 
               weight = 2,
               options = pathOptions(pane = "hood_borders")) %>% 

 # Add hood fill
  addPolygons(data = hood_shp,
              fillColor = ~pal(be_per_cap),
              fillOpacity = 1.0,
              color = NA,
              options = pathOptions(pane = "hoods",

              # Highlight neighbourhoods upon mouseover - NOT CORRECT
              highlight = highlightOptions(
                          stroke = 4),

              # Add label info when mouseover
              label = labels,
              labelOptions = labelOptions(
                style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"),
                textsize = "15px",
                direction = "auto")))
```

---

Taking what SeGa advised, I've modified the code. See [here](https://lawsblog.netlify.com/post/leaflet-map/). The neighbourhood borders are not obscured and the border does expand upon hover. However the border does not revert back to its original width with mouse out. Why is that?

```
leaflet(options = leafletOptions(minZoom = 11, maxZoom = 16), width = "100%") %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 

  # Raster image surrounding Toronto
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap.BlackAndWhite) %>% 

#  Center map north of Toronto City Hall slightly zoomed in
  setView(map,
          lng = -79.384293,
          lat = 43.685, #43.653908,
          zoom = 12) %>%

  # Vector neighbourhoods
  addPolygons(data = hood_shp, 
              fillColor = ~pal(be_per_cap),
              color = NA,
              fillOpacity = 1,

              # Highlight neighbourhoods upon mouseover
              highlight = highlightOptions(
                weight = 3,
                fillOpacity = 0,
                color = "black",
                opacity = 1.0,
                bringToFront = TRUE,
                sendToBack = TRUE),  

              # # Add label info when mouseover
              label = labels,
              labelOptions = labelOptions(
              style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"),
              textsize = "15px",
              direction = "auto")) %>%

  # Add highways
  addPolygons(data = xway,
              color = "sienna",
              weight = 1.0,
              opacity = 1.0,
              fillOpacity = 0.7) %>%

  # Add major arterial
  addPolygons(data = mart,
              color = "#737373",
              weight = 1.0,
              opacity = 1.0,
              fillOpacity = 1.0) %>%

  # Add parks
  addPolygons(data = parks,
              color = "green",
              weight = 1.0,
              opacity = 1.0,
              fillOpacity = 1.0,
              options = pathOptions(clickable = FALSE)) %>%

  # Add border
  addPolylines(data = hood_shp,
               color = "black",
               stroke = TRUE,
               opacity = 1, 
               weight = 1) %>% 

  # Add legend
  addLegend(data = hood_shp, 
            colors =c("#AA122E", "#F4AE7E", "#FEFDB7"),
            labels= c("More", "", "Less"),
            opacity = 1.0, 
            title = "B&Es",
            position = "bottomright")
```

Comment: If you would include a small reproducible example with some dummy data, it would be easier solving it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly but if you only want to increase the borders of a polygon with leaflet, the highlightoption is the right choice, but you shouldn't place it inside the pathOptions.

- The following example uses `addPolygons` for the **neighboorhoods** with a highlightOption. Within those you define the behaviour of the neighboorhoods when mouse-overing. With the `weight` argument you define the border size.
- The **parks** also go in an `addPolygons` but with `options =
  pathOptions(clickable = FALSE)` you make them unclickable, so they
  dont interact with mouse events.
- And the **borders** go in a `addPolylines` without any further
  options.

Is the following example what you are looking for?

```
library(sp)

Sr1 = Polygon(cbind(c(2,4,4,1,2),c(2,3,5,4,2)))
Sr2 = Polygon(cbind(c(5,4,2,5),c(2,3,2,2)))
Srs1 = Polygons(list(Sr1), "s1")
Srs2 = Polygons(list(Sr2), "s2")
hood_shp = SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1,Srs2), 1:2)
hood_shp <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(hood_shp, data=data.frame(be_per_cap = 1:length(hood_shp)), match.ID = F)

parks = Polygon(cbind(c(2,3,3,1,2),c(1,2,4,3,1)))
parks = SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(parks), "parks")))

xway = Polygon(cbind(c(1,5,5,1,3),c(3,5,5,3,1)))
xway = SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(xway), "xway")))

library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({

      pal = colorBin("Blues", hood_shp$be_per_cap)

      leaflet(width = "100%") %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 

        # Raster image surrounding Toronto
        addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap.BlackAndWhite) %>% 

        # Vector neighbourhoods
        addPolygons(data = hood_shp, 
                    fillColor = ~pal(be_per_cap),
                    color = "transparent",
                    fillOpacity = 1,

                    # Highlight neighbourhoods upon mouseover
                    highlight = highlightOptions(
                      weight = 3,
                      fillOpacity = 0,
                      color = "black",
                      opacity = 1.0,
                      bringToFront = TRUE,
                      sendToBack = TRUE),  

                    # # Add label info when mouseover
                    label = "labels",
                    labelOptions = labelOptions(
                      style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"),
                      textsize = "15px",
                      direction = "auto")) %>%

        # Add parks
        addPolygons(data = parks,
                    color = "green",
                    weight = 1.0,
                    opacity = 1.0,
                    fillOpacity = 1.0,
                    options = pathOptions(clickable = FALSE)) %>%

        # Add highways
        addPolygons(data = xway,
                    color = "sienna",
                    weight = 1.0,
                    opacity = 1.0,
                    fillOpacity = 0.7) %>%

        # Add border
        addPolylines(data = hood_shp,
                     color = "black",
                     stroke = TRUE,
                     opacity = 1, 
                     weight = 1) %>% 

        # Add legend
        addLegend(data = hood_shp, 
                  colors =c("#AA122E", "#F4AE7E", "#FEFDB7"),
                  labels= c("More", "", "Less"),
                  opacity = 1.0, 
                  title = "B&Es",
                  position = "bottomright")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I can get the borders to highlight if I don't use layers. See: https://lawsblog.netlify.com/post/leaflet-map/  However, I believe I need to use layers so the "park" layer does not obscure the white neighbourhood borders. Does that make sense?

Comment: I edited my answer. Maybe that is what you're after?

Comment: I've tried to take your example and apply it. It's not clear to me as to how you control layer order. Also, I've modified my original question with my changes. I still have an issue of the border not returning to its original width upon mouse out.

Comment: It works for me. Try out with `weight = 10` in the highlightOptions of the neighbourhoods. What is your desired behaviour? What should be clickable and what just displayed?

Comment: The desired behaviour is to widen the black border upon hover and to return the width of the border to its original state upon mouse out. I think this works perfectly when the border lies over a green park. But when the border it not over a park  it looks different when I mouse out after hovering. Does that make sense? No clicking is required.

Comment: It makes sense, but I dont see why my example doesnt fit your requirements? It widens the borders upon mouse-over and returns them to original state when mouse-out. What is missing? Or is the behaviour correct and its just not working in your app?

Comment: My apologies, I forgot the link when I updated the question. If you look here (https://lawsblog.netlify.com/post/leaflet-map/) and move the mouse around the borders become thicker and stay that way.

Comment: Try with `color = "transparent"` for the neighboordhoods instead of `NA`. I'll include it in my answer.

Comment: Great job, thanks! Where do you recommend I look to learn more about leaflet-R?

Comment: Good question.. Apart from their [manual](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/), I would say Github repos, [RShiny gallery](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/), StackOverflow, Youtube, Google ;).. And of course trial-error is your best coach ;)